# How to pretty print the contents of a sync Map

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to pretty print the contents of a sync map in Go. 
I have a sync.Map `data` I want to print the contents of it.

To view the value of a specific key `SiteData` I can run the following code.

```
var data sync.Map
siteData := map[string]string{"Name": "StackOverflow"}
data.Store("SiteData", siteData)
temp, _ := data.Load("SiteData") 
b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(temp, "", " ")
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

But I wish to print the entire map at once. This is because the `data` can have many keys and I want to print them at once.

Running the below code doesn't work and prints `{}`

```
var data sync.Map
siteData := map[string]string{"Name": "StackOverflow"}
data.Store("SiteData", siteData)
b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", " ")
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: Use sync.Map.Range and implement prettyprinting yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution so far

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fields (internals) of [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) are not exported, so they can't be accessed, and more importantly they can't be accessed without synchronization. So you can't just print the contents of a `sync.Map`.

What you may do is iterate over all entries of your `sync.Map`, build an "ordinary" map from it, and display that. Note that the "ordinary" map must have `string` key type (maps with `interface{}` key type are not supported by the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package). We may simply convert `interface{}` keys to `string` using [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint). To get all entries, you may use [`Map.Range()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map.Range).

For example:

```
var data sync.Map
data.Store("SiteData", map[string]string{
    "Name": "StackOverflow",
    "Url":  "https://so.com",
})
data.Store("Else", "something else")

m := map[string]interface{}{}
data.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
    m[fmt.Sprint(key)] = value
    return true
})

b, err := json.MarshalIndent(m, "", " ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MgcqZlmqqJX)):

```
{
 "Else": "something else",
 "SiteData": {
  "Name": "StackOverflow",
  "Url": "https://so.com"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple util function *(you may modify base on it as need)*:

```
// print map's key/value, with index (not stable),
func PrintSyncMap(m sync.Map) {
    // print map,
    fmt.Println("map content:")
    i := 0
    m.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
        fmt.Printf("\t[%d] key: %v, value: %v\n", i, key, value)
        i++
        return true
    })
}
```

Example output:

```
map content:
        [0] key: Qian, value: class 2
        [1] key: Zhao, value: class 1
        [2] key: Li, value: class 4
```

**Tips:**

- Index is not stable. (aka. Order of printed item may change among multiple calls.)